# How can i make a group of entries in python tkinter work like an excel sheet by pressing enter and tab to move cells

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Please how can I make the entries I've created work like an Excel sheet, so that when I press enter it goes to the next cell (entry) along that column or when I press tab it's takes me to the next cell (entry) along that row.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```py
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import *


class Example():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.table = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.table.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        name = Label(self.table, font=("Helvetica", 10, "bold"), text='Company').grid(row=0, column=0,sticky=W)
        year1 = Label(self.table, font=("Helvetica", 10, "bold"), text='1999').grid(row=0, column=1,sticky=E)
        year2 = Label(self.table, font=("Helvetica", 10, "bold"), text='2000').grid(row=0, column=2,sticky=E)
        year3 = Label(self.table, font=("Helvetica", 10, "bold"), text='2001').grid(row=0, column=3,sticky=E)

        # Setting values for the first column as string variables
        me1 = StringVar()
        me2 = StringVar()
        me3 = StringVar()
        me4 = StringVar()
        me5 = StringVar()
        me6 = StringVar()
        me7 = StringVar()

        # Setting values for the second column as float variables
        dwe1 = DoubleVar()
        dwe2 = DoubleVar()
        dwe3 = DoubleVar()
        dwe4 = DoubleVar()
        dwe5 = DoubleVar()
        dwe6 = DoubleVar()
        dwe7 = DoubleVar()

        # Setting values for the third column as float variables
        fpe1 = DoubleVar()
        fpe2 = DoubleVar()
        fpe3 = DoubleVar()
        fpe4 = DoubleVar()
        fpe5 = DoubleVar()
        fpe6 = DoubleVar()
        fpe7 = DoubleVar()

        # Setting values for the fourth column as float variables
        bfe1 = DoubleVar()
        bfe2 = DoubleVar()
        bfe3 = DoubleVar()
        bfe4 = DoubleVar()
        bfe5 = DoubleVar()
        bfe6 = DoubleVar()
        bfe7 = DoubleVar()

        # Putting each of the values in a list for easy calling latter
        rt = [0,[me1,dwe1,fpe1,bfe1],[me2,dwe2,fpe2,bfe2],[me3,dwe3,fpe3,bfe3],[me4,dwe4,fpe4,bfe4],[me5,dwe5,fpe5,bfe5],[me6,dwe6,fpe6,bfe6],[me7,dwe7,fpe7,bfe7]]


        self.rows = []
        for row in range(1,8):
            row_entries = []
            self.rows.append(row_entries)
            for column in range(4):
                entry = tk.Entry(self.table,width=10, textvariable=rt[row][column], bd=4, bg='white')
                entry.grid(row=row, column=column)
                row_entries.append(entry)

                entry.bind("<Return>", self.handle_enter)

    def handle_enter(self, event):
        # get the row and column of the entry that got the event
        entry = event.widget
        row = int(entry.grid_info()['row'])
        column = int(entry.grid_info()['column'])

        # compute the new row; either the next row or circle
        # back around to the first row
        new_row = row if row < len(self.rows) else 0

        # get the entry for the new row, and set focus to it
        entry = self.rows[new_row][column]
        entry.focus_set()

example = Example()

tk.mainloop()
```

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd47R.jpg)

Comment: This is mostly just the code from my answer, where you added some variables. It's a little dishonest to steal the code from another answer without giving proper credit.

Comment: This code also has the problem that you create a bunch of variables for the entries, but you don't save them so you will not be able to use them anywhere else in your program except inside the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've created the rows in order from left to right and top to bottom, the behavior of the tab key will automatically do what you want.

To move up and down between rows, you need to bind to the `<Return>` event. The bound function needs to determine the current row and then set the focus to the next row.

Here's a working example that illustrates the technique of saving the entry widgets in a list of lists so any given widget can be easily retrieved by the row and column number, and using `grid` and `grid_info` to determine which row and column a widget is in.

In this example, the focus is moved to the top row if you press the return key on the bottom row.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.table = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.table.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.rows = []
        for row in range(10):
            row_entries = []
            self.rows.append(row_entries)
            for column in range(4):
                entry = tk.Entry(self.table)
                entry.grid(row=row, column=column)
                row_entries.append(entry)

                entry.bind("<Return>", self.handle_enter)

    def handle_enter(self, event):
        # get the row and column of the entry that got the event
        entry = event.widget
        row = int(entry.grid_info()['row'])
        column = int(entry.grid_info()['column'])

        # compute the new row; either the next row or circle
        # back around to the first row
        new_row = row+1 if row+1 < len(self.rows) else 0

        # get the entry for the new row, and set focus to it
        entry = self.rows[new_row][column]
        entry.focus_set()

example = Example()
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Bryan Oakley. This is exactly what i need.

Comment: Please sir, what do I do if I want to call an integea in a cell for a calculation. That is, assuming in several cells I input numbers, what do I do if I want to call or reference the numbers in some particular cells for a calculation elsewhere.

Comment: Now, for instance, if i put a float on two cells say 2.5 and 7.89. And i want to use a button which has an "event" that would calculate the multiplication of these two inputs. How do i assign a "value" to these cells so i can use the "get()" function to call/get the numbers inputted on any cell i want. Thanks a million so far.

Comment: @AwomaVICTORSEGUN: you would call `get` on `rows[2][5]` and `rows[7][89]`, convert the values to a float, and then multiply them. For example, `float(self.rows[2][5].get()) * float(self.rows[7][89].get())`.